# Link selecionado ao mudar o slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-eventos, owl-carousel

Boa tarde,

Estou precisando de uma ajuda, sou novo em Javascript, Jquery, etc. Estou desenvolvendo um projeto e criei uma parte com Owl Carousel 2 onde o Slider muda conforme eu clico nos links do alfabeto. Ao clicar no link do alfabeto, o slider muda conforme o nome da pessoa e insere mais um link com o nome da pessoa abaixo do alfabeto, pois o alfabeto irá trazer o nome das pessoas conforme a primeira inicial de seu nome.

**O que preciso:** Preciso fazer o comportamento inverso, ou seja, que eu possa mudar o slide através das setas e o slider selecionado apareça selecionado no link do alfabeto e o nome da pessoa apareça abaixo dele.

Outra dúvida, eu fiz um Javascript grande para que quando eu clicasse em outro link, ele removesse os demais. Gostaria de saber se existe outra alternativa para simplificar esse código, pois acho que ficou muito repetitivo e grande.

Poderiam me ajudar?

```js
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    items:1,
    loop:true,
    nav:true,
    URLhashListener:true,
    autoplayHoverPause:true,
    startPosition: 'URLHash'
});


$('.nav-link').click(function(){
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
});


$(document).ready(function(){

    // DIV QUE SERÁ AFETADA AO ADICIONAR ELEMENTOS DINÂMICOS
    var divPai = $('.nome-pessoas');

    // VARIÁVEIS DOS IDS DO LINK DO ALFABETO
    var b = $('#b');
    var c = $('#c');
    var f = $('#f');
    var h = $('#h');
    var j = $('#j');
    var n = $('#n');
    var p = $('#p');
    var r = $('#r');
    var v = $('#v');

    b.click(function(){
        divPai.append("<a class='nav-link active' id='bianca' href='#8'>Bianca</a>");
        $('#carlos').remove();
        $('#felipe').remove();
        $('#heitor').remove();
        $('#joao').remove();
        $('#nelson').remove();
        $('#paulo').remove();
        $('#renato').remove();
        $('#roberta').remove();
        $('#viviane').remove();
    });

    c.click(function(){
        divPai.append("<a class='nav-link active' id='carlos' href='#2'>Carlos</a>");
        $('#bianca').remove();
        $('#felipe').remove();
        $('#heitor').remove();
        $('#joao').remove();
        $('#nelson').remove();
        $('#paulo').remove();
        $('#renato').remove();
        $('#roberta').remove();
        $('#viviane').remove();
    });

    f.click(function(){
        divPai.append("<a class='nav-link active' id='felipe' href='#6'>Felipe</a>");
        $('#carlos').remove();
        $('#bianca').remove();
        $('#heitor').remove();
        $('#joao').remove();
        $('#nelson').remove();
        $('#paulo').remove();
        $('#renato').remove();
        $('#roberta').remove();
        $('#viviane').remove();
    });

    h.click(function(){
        divPai.append("<a class='nav-link active' id='heitor' href='#10'>Heitor</a>");
        $('#carlos').remove();
        $('#bianca').remove();
        $('#felipe').remove();
        $('#joao').remove();
        $('#nelson').remove();
        $('#paulo').remove();
        $('#renato').remove();
        $('#roberta').remove();
        $('#viviane').remove();
    });

    j.click(function(){
        divPai.append("<a class='nav-link active' id='joao' href='#1'>João</a>");
        $('#carlos').remove();
        $('#bianca').remove();
        $('#heitor').remove();
        $('#felipe').remove();
        $('#nelson').remove();
        $('#paulo').remove();
        $('#renato').remove();
        $('#roberta').remove();
        $('#viviane').remove();
    });

    n.click(function(){
        divPai.append("<a class='nav-link active' id='nelson'  href='#9'>Nelson</a>");
        $('#carlos').remove();
        $('#bianca').remove();
        $('#heitor').remove();
        $('#joao').remove();
        $('#felipe').remove();
        $('#paulo').remove();
        $('#renato').remove();
        $('#roberta').remove();
        $('#viviane').remove();
    });

    p.click(function(){
        divPai.append("<a class='nav-link active' id='paulo' href='#5'>Paulo</a>");
        $('#carlos').remove();
        $('#bianca').remove();
        $('#heitor').remove();
        $('#joao').remove();
        $('#nelson').remove();
        $('#felipe').remove();
        $('#renato').remove();
        $('#roberta').remove();
        $('#viviane').remove();
    });

    r.click(function(){
        divPai.append("<a class='nav-link active' id='renato' href='#3'>Renato</a>");
        divPai.append("<a class='nav-link' id='roberta' href='#7'>Roberta</a>");
        $('#carlos').remove();
        $('#felipe').remove();
        $('#heitor').remove();
        $('#joao').remove();
        $('#nelson').remove();
        $('#paulo').remove();
        $('#bianca').remove();
        $('#viviane').remove();

        $('.nav-link').click(function(){
            $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
        });
    });

    v.click(function(){
        divPai.append("<a class='nav-link active' id='viviane' href='#4'>Viviane</a>");
        $('#carlos').remove();
        $('#felipe').remove();
        $('#heitor').remove();
        $('#joao').remove();
        $('#nelson').remove();
        $('#paulo').remove();
        $('#renato').remove();
        $('#roberta').remove();
        $('#bianca').remove();
    });




});
```

```css
.conteudo-nosso-time{
    padding: 30% 0 0% 0; 
}

.conteudo-nosso-time h1{
    font-family: PublicoTextRoman;
    color: #082933;
    font-size: 3.3vw;
}

.conteudo-nosso-time h2{
    font-family: AkkuratProBold;
    color:#082933;
    font-size: 1.5vmin;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.conteudo-nosso-time p{
    font-family: AkkuratLight;
    font-size: 1em;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.conteudo-nosso-time hr{
    border-top: solid 1px #d0ab67;
}

.conteudo-nosso-time .nav .disabled{
    color: #c0c0c0;
    padding: 0 0.5rem;
    font-family: PublicoTextRoman;
    font-size: 18px;
}

.conteudo-nosso-time .nav .nav-link{
    padding: 0 0.5rem;
    font-family: PublicoTextRoman;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #6c6c6c;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.conteudo-nosso-time .nav .nav-link:hover{
    color: #d0ab67;
    font-weight: bolder;
}

.conteudo-nosso-time .nav .nav-link.active{
    color: #d0ab67;
    font-weight: bolder;
}

.conteudo-nosso-time .separador-alfabeto{
    color: #c0c0c0;
}

.conteudo-nosso-time .nome-pessoas{
   margin-top: 30px;
}

.conteudo-nosso-time .nome-pessoas .nav-link{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 2px 8px;
    font-family: PublicoTextRoman;
    color:#6c6c6c;
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-size: 30px;  
}

.conteudo-nosso-time .nome-pessoas .nav-link:hover{
    color: #d0ab67;
}

.conteudo-nosso-time .nome-pessoas .nav-link.active{
    color: #d0ab67;
}

.carossel-pessoas{
    padding:15% 0;
}

.owl-carousel .item img{
    display: block;
}

.owl-carousel .item h1{
    background-color: #000;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 7%;
    text-align: center;
    top: 89%;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 1.8vw;
    font-family: PublicoTextRoman;
}

.owl-dots{
    display: none;
}

.owl-carousel .owl-nav{
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: -15%;
    left: 40%;
    color: #000;
    z-index: 4;
}

.owl-carousel .owl-nav .owl-prev span, .owl-next span{
    font-size: 2.0vw;
    padding: 0px 20px 10px 20px;
    border: solid 1px #d0ab67;
}

.owl-carousel .owl-nav .owl-prev span:hover, .owl-next span:hover{
    background-color:  #d0ab67;
}


.owl-carousel .owl-nav button:focus{
    outline-style: none;
    background-color: none;
}


@font-face {
    font-family: 'Akkurat-Bold';
    src: url('fonts/akkurat/Akkurat-Bold.ttf');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'AkkuratProBold';
    src: url('fonts/akkurat/AkkuratProBold.otf');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'AkkuratLight';
    src: url('fonts/akkurat/AkkuratLight.ttf');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'PublicoTextRoman';
    src: url('fonts/publico/PublicoTextRoman.OTF');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Carousel</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.theme.default.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="fonts.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>
<body>


    <!-- NOSSO TIME -->
    <div class="row p-0 m-0">
        <div class="col-md-2"></div>
        <!-- COLUNA ESQUERDA -->
        <div class="col-md-3">
            
            <div class="conteudo-nosso-time">

                <hr>    
                <!-- ALFABETO -->
                <nav class="nav">
                    <div class="disabled">A</div><span class="separador-alfabeto">|</span>
                    <a class="nav-link" id="b" href="#8">B</a><span class="separador-alfabeto">|</span>
                    <a class="nav-link" id="c" href="#2">C</a><span class="separador-alfabeto">|</span>
                    <div class="disabled">D</div><span class="separador-alfabeto">|</span>
                    <div class="disabled">E</div><span class="separador-alfabeto">|</span>
                    <a class="nav-link" id="f" href="#6">F</a><span class="separador-alfabeto">|</span>
                    <div class="disabled" href="#">G</div><span class="separador-alfabeto">|</span>
                    <a class="nav-link" id="h" href="#10">H</a><span class="separador-alfabeto">|</span>
                    <div class="disabled">I</div><span class="separador-alfabeto">|</span>
                    <a class="nav-link active" id="j" href="#1">J</a><span class="separador-alfabeto">|</span>
                    <div class="disabled">L</div><span class="separador-alfabeto">|</span>
                    <div class="disabled">M</div><span class="separador-alfabeto">|</span>
                    <a class="nav-link" id="n" href="#9">N</a><span class="separador-alfabeto">|</span>
                    <div class="disabled">O</div><span class="separador-alfabeto">|</span>
                    <a class="nav-link" id="p" href="#5">P</a><span class="separador-alfabeto">|</span>
                    <div class="disabled">Q</div><span class="separador-alfabeto">|</span>
                    <a class="nav-link" id="r" href="#3">R</a><span class="separador-alfabeto">|</span>
                    <div class="disabled">S</div><span class="separador-alfabeto">|</span>
                    <div class="disabled">T</div><span class="separador-alfabeto">|</span>
                    <div class="disabled">U</div><span class="separador-alfabeto">|</span>
                    <a class="nav-link" id="v" href="#4">V</a><span class="separador-alfabeto">|</span>
                    <div class="disabled">X</div><span class="separador-alfabeto">|</span>
                    <div class="disabled">Z</div>
                </nav>

                <!-- LINK COM O NOME DAS PESSOAS -->
                <div class="nome-pessoas"></div>

            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="col-md-1"></div>
        <div class="col-md-4">        

            <div class="carossel-pessoas">
                <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme" data-spy="scroll"> 
                    <div class="item" data-hash="1"><h1>João</h1></div>
                    <div class="item" data-hash="2"><h1>Carlos</h1></div>
                    <div class="item" data-hash="3"><h1>Renato</h1></div>
                    <div class="item" data-hash="4"><h1>Viviane</h1></div>
                    <div class="item" data-hash="5"><h1>Paulo</h1></div>
                    <div class="item" data-hash="6"><h1>Felipe</h1></div>
                    <div class="item" data-hash="7"><h1>Roberta</h1></div>
                    <div class="item" data-hash="8"><h1>Bianca</h1></div>
                    <div class="item" data-hash="9"><h1>Nelson</h1></div>
                    <div class="item" data-hash="10"><h1>Heitor</h1></div>                
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="col-md-2"></div>
    </div>

    


        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.js"></script>
        <script src="site.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Cara, eu ainda não terminei. Mas eu fiz um exemplo de uma das maneiras de como tu poderia reduzir esse código. Da uma olhada nesse código e ve te da uma ajuda: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-k6kb8y?file=index.js

Comment: Opa Paulo tudo bem? Cara, show de bola, reduziu bem o código, vou dar uma mexida nele aqui, eu tirei o "if" pois não quero que delete as letras do alfabeto, apenas fique com o css ativo ao clicar, que já tem no código. E eu precisava que, quando clicar, aparecer o nome das pessoas ao invés da letra, e quando clicar em outra letra do alfabeto, apagasse o que tava anteriormente, vai ser como se fosse um filtro por nome. Vou dar uma fuçada hoje, mas ajudou amigo. Preciso resolver para que tenha o comportamento quando eu mudar o slide.